# How should I check if a .NET decimal value is a whole number?

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal

I have class representing a unit of measure with a `Decimal` as the numeric.  Just to simplify things for this example, let's say I'm representing centimeters.  I'd like to implement a ToString() method for this class.  The thing is, if the numeric value is a whole number I'd like to just display the decimal as an integer.  Otherwise, I'd like to keep it as a decimal.  So, for example, 10.5D centimeters would display as "10.5cm", but 7.0D centimeters should display as "7cm".  I'd like this to be fast and simple to read.  I have a working solution, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Here's a contrived example showing my first crack at it:

```
Public Property Units As String = "cm"
Public Property NumericValue As Decimal = 10.5D

Public Overrides Function ToString()
   Dim num As String = If(Me.NumericValue = Decimal.Ceiling(Me.NumericValue), _
                          Decimal.ToInt32(Me.NumericValue).ToString(), _ 
                          Me.NumericValue.ToString())
   Return num + Me.Units
End Function
```

I'm a little uncomfortable with `Me.NumericValue = Decimal.Ceiling(Me.NumericValue)`.  Any thoughts on how to do this better?  Is there something I could do with String.Format or some other method on the Decimal class that would make this clearer and keep it performant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
decimal.Truncate(myDecimal) == myDecimal
```

This might be good enough for your purposes. However, this a complex issue; simply using `System.Decimal` does not get rid of all problems related to floating-point representations. The code-sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) is a case in point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
    Public Overrides Function ToString() 
        If (Me.NumericValue - Math.Round(Me.NumericValue, 0) > 0) Then
                Return String.Format("{0:###,###,##0.00}{1}", Me.NumericValue, Units);
        Return String.Format("{0:###,###,##0}{1}", Me.NumericValue, Units)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this?

Anyone with an enginerring background will read "7cm" as "approx. seven centimeters" and "7.00cm" as "seven centimetres to the nearest millimeter".

Comment: It's a contrived example.  I'm actually parsing CSS from an XHTML document and writing a class that represents the numeric values with units like px, em, cm, in, %, etc.  So yes, I want 7cm, not 7.0cm.